# D3 + Typescript Code to tile multiple plots for a Rocket Launch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'd like some help in creating a plot similar to the one I drew in the picture below. I have one-second data for a rocket launch that has taken off and I'd like to see the data in this sort of plot...

1. One y axis on the left showing time and the resulting height separate
2. Plot for each variable. y(x) "variable as a function of time/height"
3. Finally I'd like to be able to plot multiple launches so I can
       compare them (blue is launch 1, green is launch 2)

** Edit: on plots comparing different launches do not show time, just height. On plots with just one launch show time and height.

**Here is a code pen of my attempt** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-night-qo88q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

to supply data for this plot you can use random data like this

```
const now = new Date();
const data = Array(100).fill('').map((_,i) => ({
  time: new Date(now.getTime() + i*1000),
  height: i,
  velocity: Math.floor(Math.random() * 300),
  acceleration: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  fuel: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)/100
}));
```

[image: Rocket Launch]

Comment: Please add what have you tried so far? Asking to draw the entire plot from scratch is too broad for a question here.

Comment: @Coola thanks, I have uploaded my attempt. I wasn't able to get my lines to draw and I couldn't get d3.extent() to work due to typescript errors, but overall it's pretty close to what I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw the lines you will need to append a path to the `svg`. To do so we replace:

```
    var line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d: any) => x(d[key]))
        .y((d: any) => x(d[yAxisVariable]));
```

with

```
// to plot the lines
 svg
    .datum(data)
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "dataline")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { 
            return x(d[`${key}`]) ;
        })
        .y(function(d) { 
            return y(d.height) ;
        })
        )
```

Also we need to move this below the

```
    svg2.append('g').call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

So that it appends after the svg and grid have been drawn.

Now, in your application, when I do this, it produces the line if you console.log as a path. However, for some reason there is a class getting attached to the path which is making it disappear (with stroke-width: 0). I do not know how to override this. I tried to mention stroke-width as an attribute but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
.makeStyles-trace-949 path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

The number `949` in the above class keeps changing and I do not know where in your code that is coming from. 
In the browser console if you disable this class you will be able to see the line.

Here is a screenshot of the console

[image]

**Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sunset-wbqzv).**

Here is a screenshot once you disable that css class:

[image]

I have not investigated why the lines go off the chart but I suspect it has something to do with the margins and the domain-range mapping for the x-axis.

Currently since all the data comes together both Launch A and B plots are all together. That is why you see one line going across as when all the points of Launch A are done, it connects the last point of Launch A to the first point of Launch B. You can consider nesting your data for your launches and then plotting lines individually for each nested data. Check out this guide on [nesting and grouping data](http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you look at this question I asked about now applying a y-axis tooltip? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399969/d3-tooltip-bar-for-multi-line-chart-on-mouseover-on-y-axis-code-supplied @Coola