# d3 tooltip bar for multi line chart on mouseover on Y Axis (code supplied)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a tooltip on mouseover for a multi line chart. 
I've followed the code from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91) and tried to change it so that I see the X values of the lines for a given hovered Y value, but I'm not able to get it to work.

My attempt can be found below.

In my actual implementation I'm writing in Typescript and the functions 'getTotalLength()' and 'getPointAtLength()' are saying they don't exist on property Element.
Also if you can add a text box at on the line that has the hovered Y value that'd help me a lot!

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-minsky-hvsms?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks

Comment: You're using `this` in  your arrow functions. But arrow functions don't have bindings to `this`

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

So after careful review there were several errors which I have corrected.

1. Your paths for the data lines were not assigned the class so you need to assign the class of `dataLine` to them when you append them like so:

```
    svg
      .selectAll(".dataLine")
      .data(nestedData)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("class", "dataLine")
      .attr("stroke", d => itemMap(d.key).color)
      .attr("stroke-width", d => itemMap(d.key).lineWeight)
      .attr("d", d =>
        d3
          .line()
          .x(d => x(d.xvalue))
          .y(d => y(d.yvalue))(d.values)
      );
```

2. As pointed out in the comment above, stop using arrow functions if you intend to use this. Once you do that, your `d3.mouse(this)` starts working.
3. The example you followed had the paths from left to right, while yours is from top to bottom. This required several changes in terms of coordinates to get the alignment of the mouseover line and the circles with the text values near them to align properly. The correct code is as follows:

```
      .on("mousemove", function() {
        //@ts-ignore
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line").attr("d", () => {
          var d = "M" + plotWidth + "," + mouse[1];
          d += " " + 0 + "," + mouse[1];
          return d;
        });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line").attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          var yDepth = y.invert(mouse[1]);
          var bisect = d3.bisector(d => d.depth).right;
          var idy = bisect(d.values, yDepth);

          var beginning = 0;
          var end = lines[i].getTotalLength();
          var target = null;

          while (true) {
            target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
            var pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
            if (
              (target === end || target === beginning) &&
              pos.y !== mouse[1]
            ) {
              break;
            }
            if (pos.y > mouse[1]) {
              end = target;
            } else if (pos.y < mouse[1]) {
              beginning = target;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          d3.select(this)
            .select("text")
            .text(x.invert(pos.x).toFixed(2));

          return "translate(" + pos.x + "," + mouse[1] + ")";
        });
      });
```

[Fully working codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cdn-qk9ex).